# Opening and closing cupboards

Tags: game-theory

> Sasha is playing a game. She has $43$ cupboards lined up in a row, and each cupboard is initially open. On her first move, she picks and closes one cupboard. Then, on her second move, she picks two adjacent cupboards independent of the first move and closes the cupboard if it is open and opens the cupboard if it is closed. On her third move, she picks three adjacent cupboards and does the same thing. She continues doing this until she has made $43$ moves. Is it possible for all of the cupboards to be closed after she finishes her $43$ moves?

---

I first noted that all of the cupboards after the $42$nd move have to be open, but I wasn't sure where to go from here.

Comment: What have you tried?  A natural starting point would be to do the same problem with $n$ cupboards instead of $43$.  If $n$ is small, you can easily do it by hand...perhaps a pattern emerges.

Comment: I'm finding that numbers $1 \pmod{4}$ work, but how should I prove/disprove this rigorously?

Comment: How are you seeing that?  $4$ works, for example. Starting with $0000$ to mean four open cupboards, we go $0000\mapsto 1000\mapsto 1110\mapsto 0000\mapsto 1111$.  Or have I misunderstood the rules?

Comment: Ah, I missed that. However, is there a rigorous way to prove this?

Comment: A rigorous way to prove what?  As a suggestion, I think it is a lot easier to prove that certain cases are impossible.  I'd go for that first.

Comment: How should I go about doing that?

Comment: To have all the cupboards closed after the 43 move, as defined by your question, all boards need to be open after the 42 move.

Comment: Well, try.  Since $43\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ it's natural to try to prove that $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$ is impossible.  As a hint:  suppose, to the contrary, that we have a way of doing it and let $d_i$ be the number of times door $i$ is changed.  What can you say about $\sum d_i$?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not quite sure. Could you expand on that a little bit in an answer?

Comment: Please try.  That's a strong hint, work with it.

Answer (score 0):

If there are $n$ cupboards then let the number $s = s_1 s_2 s_3\dots s_n$ represent which cupboards are open and which are closed. If $s_i = 1$ then cupboard $i$ is open and if $s_i = 0$ then it is closed. For example $s=10010$ means that there is $5$ cupboards and cupboard $1$ and $5$ are open. A move $m = m_1m_2\dots m_n$ specifies which cupboards are being changed. The term $m_j = 1$ means cupboard $j$ is changing (if the cupboard $j$ was open $m_j=1$ means it is being closed and if $j$ was closed $m_j=1$ means it is being open) and $m_j=0$ means the cupboard is being left alone. Let $m(i)$ represent move $i$, i.e., $m(3)$ means that this is move three where $3$ cupboards are changed. Your goal is to find a sequence of moves $m(1), m(2), \dots, m(n)$ to change $s=111\dots 1$ to $000\dots 0$.

Here are some hints to help you out:

- When you perform a move, is it the same as $s\oplus m$ where $\oplus$ is the xor operation?
- If you make move $m$ first and then move $t$ second is it different than move $t$ first and move $m$ second, i.e., Does $(s\oplus m)\oplus t$ equal $(s\oplus t)\oplus m$?
- Is there a pairing strategy you can make? For $n=5$ notice that if $m(1) = 10000$ and $m(4)=01111$ then $m(1)\oplus m(4) = 11111$. Similarly, $m(2)=11000$ and $m(3)=00111$ then $m(2)\oplus m(3) = 11111$. Can you use this to your advantage? Can you use this to solve the problem for any $n$?
- If $s$ has $p$ number of $1$'s in it and $m$ has $q$ number of $1$'s in it, how does the number of $1$'s change on $s\oplus m$, i.e., odd or even number of $1$'s?

Hopefully, this is enough of a hint for you to figure out the rest.